# How can I switch from Kubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: kubuntu, desktop-environments

I'm using Kubuntu but I want to install Ubuntu Desktop and want to use it, somehow I am unable to install.
Could anybody help me?

I tried this command:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

Output is:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-desktop : Depends: gdm3 but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: ibus
                  Recommends: ibus-table but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: shotwell but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

```
apt update
All packages are up to date.

apt upgrade 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

apt-cache policy ubuntu-desktop gdm3 ibus ibus-table shotwell
ubuntu-desktop:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.417
  Version table:
     1.417 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
gdm3:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.28.0-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     3.28.0-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
ibus:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.5.17-3ubuntu4
  Version table:
     1.5.17-3ubuntu4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
ibus-table:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.9.14-3
  Version table:
     1.9.14-3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
shotwell:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.28.2-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     0.28.2-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Try to re-enable *main* repository with `sudo add-apt-repository main` and then `sudo apt update`, followed by `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: Hi @N0rbert
I did what you advised but it didn't work.

Comment: Please run `sudo apt update`, following by `sudo apt upgrade` (add errors to the question if they occur) and add output of `apt-cache policy ubuntu-desktop gdm3 ibus ibus-table shotwell` to the question.

Comment: Hi again @N0rbert, you can find the outputs in question.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I myself would re-install. Just to avoid leaving files or settings from the other desktop

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you've provided, it looks like apt is refusing to continue with the installation because it is detecting conflicting packages.

The main possibilities that come to mind are:

- There are PPAs or non-standard repositories installed.  If so, remove them.
- There are manually downloaded and installed deb files.  If so, remove them.
- Recommended packages are being treated as dependencies.  If so, turn the setting off.  (The easiest way is from within `synaptic` or perhaps `software-properties-kde`.)

Further recommendations:

- Use `aptitude` (instead of `apt` or `apt-get`) because it has a built-in dependency resolver that will suggest potential solutions that will allow the installation to continue.
- If you just want to try different desktop environments, try the live discs first to avoid destabilizing your current system.  Then if you like them, install just the associated packages (such as, `gnome` or `xfce4`), rather than `ubuntu-desktop`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your repository settings - open *Software & Updates* (or `software-properties-gtk` / `software-properties-kde`).

It should look like -

[image: Ubuntu Software tab]

[image: Updates]

Fix the differences you have, confirm reloading packages lists.
Then retry to install Ubuntu desktop with:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```