# 18.04 unable to install texlive-full (broken packages)

Tags: 18.04, latex, texlive, rstudio

I am trying to install `texlive-full` but I'm running into the same issue from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034019/18-04-cannot-install-texlive-full). However, I do not have a texlive related package from [JonathanF's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/texlive), and need a different solution.

Here's my output from `sudo apt install texlive-full`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 texlive-full : Depends: asymptote but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: biber but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: cm-super (>= 0.3.3-3) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: context but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: dvipng but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: feynmf but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: fragmaster but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: latex-cjk-all (>= 4.6.0+cvs20060714-2) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: latexmk but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: lmodern (>= 0.93.3) but it is not installable
                Depends: prerex (> 6.5.3-1) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: purifyeps but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: tex-gyre but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texinfo (>= 4.8)
                Depends: texlive-base (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not installable
                Depends: texlive-bibtex-extra (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2017.20170524.44437) but it is not installable
                Depends: texlive-extra-utils (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-font-utils (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-fonts-extra (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-fonts-extra-doc (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-fonts-extra-links (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-fonts-recommended (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-fonts-recommended-doc (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not installable
                Depends: texlive-formats-extra (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-games (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-humanities (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-humanities-doc (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-lang-arabic (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-lang-chinese (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-lang-cjk (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-lang-cyrillic (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-lang-czechslovak (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-lang-english (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-lang-european (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-lang-french (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-lang-german (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-lang-greek (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-lang-italian (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-lang-japanese (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-lang-korean (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-lang-other (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-lang-polish (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-lang-portuguese (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-lang-spanish (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-latex-base (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not installable
                Depends: texlive-latex-base-doc (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not installable
                Depends: texlive-latex-extra (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-latex-extra-doc (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-latex-recommended (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not installable
                Depends: texlive-latex-recommended-doc (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not installable
                Depends: texlive-luatex (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-metapost (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-metapost-doc (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not installable
                Depends: texlive-music (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-pictures (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-pictures-doc (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not installable
                Depends: texlive-plain-generic (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-pstricks (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-pstricks-doc (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-publishers (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-publishers-doc (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-science (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-science-doc (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-xetex (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: tipa (>= 2:1.2-2.1) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: vprerex (> 6.5.3-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Here's the output from `sudo apt-cache policy texlive-full`:

```
texlive-full:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2017.20180305-1
  Version table:
     2017.20180305-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
```

Result from running `sudo apt install aptitude`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package aptitude is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'aptitude' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: You seems to have a version conflict. Uninstall all PPA- and other non-Ubuntu versions of texlive, and disable the sources they came from, to resolve the conflict.

Comment: Do you have absolete (locally installed packages)? Please run `sudo apt install aptitude`, `aptitude search ~o` and add output of the last command to the question.

Comment: I'm getting an error just trying to install aptitude now.  See edit.