# Install texlive-full in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, latex

I'm trying to install texlive-full and unfortunately, the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034019/18-04-cannot-install-texlive-full) could not help!

Error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 texlive-full : Depends: asymptote but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: biber but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: cm-super (>= 0.3.3-3) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: context but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: dvipng but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: feynmf but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: fragmaster but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: latex-cjk-all (>= 4.6.0+cvs20060714-2) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: latexmk but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: lmodern (>= 0.93.3) but it is not installable
            Depends: prerex (> 6.5.3-1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: purifyeps but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-base (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-bibtex-extra (>= 2019.202000218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2019.20190605)
            Depends: texlive-extra-utils (>= 2019.202000218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-font-utils (>= 2019.202000218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-fonts-extra (>= 2019.202000218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-fonts-extra-doc (>= 2019.202000218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-fonts-extra-links (>= 2019.202000218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-fonts-recommended (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-fonts-recommended-doc (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-formats-extra (>= 2019.202000218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-games (>= 2019.202000218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-humanities (>= 2019.202000218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-humanities-doc (>= 2019.202000218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-arabic (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-chinese (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-cjk (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-cyrillic (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-czechslovak (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-english (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-european (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-french (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-german (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-greek (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-italian (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-japanese (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-korean (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-other (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-polish (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-portuguese (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-spanish (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-latex-base (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-latex-base-doc (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-latex-extra (>= 2019.202000218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-latex-extra-doc (>= 2019.202000218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-latex-recommended (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-latex-recommended-doc (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-luatex (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-metapost (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-metapost-doc (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-music (>= 2019.202000218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-pictures (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-pictures-doc (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-plain-generic (>= 2019.202000218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-pstricks (>= 2019.202000218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-pstricks-doc (>= 2019.202000218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-publishers (>= 2019.202000218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-publishers-doc (>= 2019.202000218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-science (>= 2019.202000218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-science-doc (>= 2019.202000218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-xetex (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: tipa (>= 2:1.2-2.1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: vprerex (> 6.5.3-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Plus I run the command `sudo apt-cache policy texlive-full` and the output is:

```
texlive-full:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 2019.20200302-1~18.04.york0
Version table:
 2019.20200302-1~18.04.york0 500
    500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
 2019.20190311-1~18.04.york0 500
    500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive-2019/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive-2019/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
 2017.20180305-1 500
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
```

From the solution above I tried to remove libkpathsea6 but it is not installed:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'libkpathsea6' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following.

Run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean 
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get updade
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:jonathonf/texlive
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

Comment: typo updade -> update

Comment: Are you having problems with fonts not showing of created pdfs? I can see my fonts on my texlive produced pdfs under Ubuntu 16.04lts but not under 18.04lts