# Dependency error: unmet dependencise

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies, 18.04

when i enter the command:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev libx11-dev libx11-dev:i386 libxtst-dev libconfig++-dev build-essential qt5-default
```

i get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.4ubuntu1).
libx11-dev is already the newest version (2:1.6.4-3).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libboost-all-dev : Depends: libboost-iostreams-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-mpi-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-mpi-python-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-regex-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libxtst-dev : Depends: libxext-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libxi-dev but it is not going to be installed
 qt5-default : Depends: qtbase5-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

how do i fix this?

RESULT OF APT-CACHE:https://pastebin.com/Ya6ycT84

edit:all of the packages have missing dependencies

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: have you tried 'sudo apt install --fix-missing' ?

Comment: i tried both commands more than a dozen times, doesnt work

Comment: the outpu of both these commande

Comment: martin@mememachine:~$ sudo apt-get install --fix-missing
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
martin@mememachine:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1034175/edit) and add output of `apt-cache policy libboost-all-dev libx11-dev libx11-dev:i386 libxtst-dev libconfig++-dev build-essential qt5-default` to it. Check images in my [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031203/66509) - do you have enabled all software sources? Also I recommend to switch to *Main server*.

Comment: im breaking it up into 2 parts since i cant post more than 8 links

Comment: Insert output in question, not comments, please.

Comment: doesnt work, i cant post more than 8 links

Comment: im putting a pastebin link here

Comment: added it, refer to the pastebin link

Comment: I do not see any problem. Try to check your repositories.

Comment: i removed sources.list, made it again with all the ubuntu servers

Comment: still doesnt work

Comment: please guys, this is for an important c++ project

Comment: Can you download every single packages and its dependencies, then do `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` ? (assuming your current directory contains downloaded packages)